# How do I define $b$ to show $(y-b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for any rational $y$?

Tags: functions

What conditions can I impose upon $b$ to make sure that $(y - b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for any $y \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Of course $b = y$ works and for $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, $b$ would just need to be an integer as well.

I mean with specific examples you're always able to construct some $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $(y - b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for any $y \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ but how can I generalise this?

The context is I wanna show that the function $f_{a,b}: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}, x \mapsto ax+b$ is surjective for specific $a,b$.

My approach was to show that for all $y$ there is a $x = \frac{y-b}{a}$ such that $f_{a,b}(x)=y$.

However $x = \frac{y-b}{a}$ needs to be rational, therefore $f_{a,b}$ is only surjective for all $a \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ and all $b$ that satisfy some condition such that $(y - b) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe I'm going all wrong about proving surjectivity?

Comment: You do know that $\frac{y-b}{a} \in \mathbb{Q}$ if $y-a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a \in \mathbb{Q}_{\neq 0}$? You don't need $y-b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Kaind Just for clarification do you mean $\frac{y-b}{a} \in \mathbb{Q}$ if $y - \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$? I don't understand how $y-a \in \mathbb{Q}$ has anything to do with it. Do you mean the quotient of two rational numbers is rational as well and therefore I only have to show $y-b$ and $a$ (with $a \neq 0 $) are rational?

Comment: @DietrichBurde As I stated in the question, $b = y$ works but doesn't cover all the cases, there are way more $b$'s with $b \neq y$ that would work.

Comment: Why do you need more than just chosing $b=y-c$ for any integer $c$? This covers more or less all cases. In any case, you should change your title, because that is not your question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The problem asks me for which $a,b$ is $f_{a,b}$ surjective.

Comment: @LinusDieLinse Yes, quotient of two rationals is a rational as long as the denominator isn't $0$. (I meant $y - b \in \mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: You can't make *any* conditions on $b$ so it works with *any* rational $y$.  If $y_1-b\in \mathbb Z$ then $y_2 = y_1 +\frac 1{10}$ we have $y_2 - b\not \in \mathbb Z$.  If we can have conditions an a *specific* $b$ to any *specific* $y$ then... you've pretty much just declared them:  For any $y \in Q$ then $y-b$ will be an integer if and only if $b=y+$ some integer.  What more needs to be said?  What more can be said? If you want terminology $b=m+ \{y\}$ where $\{y\}$ is fractional part of $y$ and $m$ is any integer.

Comment: For every $x \in \mathbb R$ there are a unique $n\in \mathbb Z$ and a unique $r \in \mathbb R; 0 \le r < 1$ where $x = n + r$.  We refer to $n$ as $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and we call it the floor integer.  $r = x -\lfloor x\rfloor$ and we refer to $r$ as $\{x\}$ and we call it "the fractional portion of $x$".  You simply need $b$ to be any integer plus $\{x\}$.  That's all you can say and that is enough.  $b = k + \{x\}$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. That's all you need.

Comment: Okay.  surjectivity.  We need that for any $q\in \mathbb Q$ there will exist an $x\in \mathbb Q$ so that $f(x) = ax + b = q$.  Okay, that just means $x =\frac {q-b}a$.  We can have $b$ be any rational and $a$ be any non-rational and that will be true.  If $q\in \mathbb Q$ then $x =\frac {q-b}a$ will be rational.  There is utterly no need to go through the headach you are putting yourself through.

Comment: "The context is I wanna show that the function fa,b:Q→Q,x↦ax+b is surjective for specific a,b."  But that has utterly no *need* to worry about when it is or is not an integer.  You don't *need* (and you can't have-- it is utterly impossible) $y-b$ always being an integer.  Why are you worrying about that? "and all b that satisfy some condition such that (y−b)∈Z." Why on earth do you think that?  All you need is $y-b\in \mathbb Q$ and that follows if $y,b\in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: "I only have to show y−b and a (with a≠0) are rational? " You don't have to *show* that.  That is a well-known fact your instructor assumes you have proven long ago and is known by everyone.  If $y =\frac mn$ and $b=\frac jk$ then $y - b = \frac mn -\frac jk = \frac {mk-nj}{nk}$ and if $a = \frac wv$ then $\frac {y-b}a = \frac {v(mk-nj)}{wnk}$.  That's a ratio of two integers and thus a rational number. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What conditions can I impose upon b to make sure that (y−b)∈Z for any y∈Q?

That is absolutely impossible.  If $y_1 -b=k \in \mathbb Z$ for $y_1\in \mathbb Q$ then $y_2 =y_1 + \frac 1{10} \in \mathbb Q$ but $y_2 = b = k+\frac 1{10}\not \in \mathbb Q$.

> However $x=\frac{y−b}a$ needs to be rational,

If $y, b, a\in \mathbb Q$ and $a\ne 0$ then $x=\frac {y-b}a$ will be rational.  That is not a problem.

> therefore fa,b is only surjective for all a∈Z∖{0} and all b that satisfy some condition such that (y−b)∈Z.

There is no need for $y-b \in \mathbb Z$.  If $y-b\in \mathbb Q$ and $a\in \mathbb Q$ (with $a\ne 0$ then $\frac {y-b}a \in \mathbb Q$.

......

Any product, sum, difference, and division (other than division by $0$) of rationals results in rationals.

If $a = \frac mn, m,n\in \mathbb Z$ and $n\ne 0$ and $m\ne 0$, and $b=\frac jk, j,k \in \mathbb Z$ and $k\ne 0$ and $y = \frac wv, w,v\in \mathbb Z$ with $v\ne 0$ then

$\frac {y-b}a =\frac {\frac wv - \frac jk}{\frac mn}=$

$\frac {\frac {wk-vj}{vk}}{\frac mn}=$

$\frac nm\cdot \frac {wk-vj}{vk} = \frac {n(wk-vj)}{mvk}$.

As $n(wk-vj)\in \mathbb Z$ and $mvk\in \mathbb Z$ and $mvk \ne 0$ we have $\frac {y-b}a= \frac {n(wk-vj)}{mvk} \in \mathbb Q$.

No problem!

Comment: Thank you very much! :D This really cleared things up for me, I'm feeling stupid now. So just for final clarification, $f_{a,b}$ is surjective for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $a \neq 0$?